# .htaccess redirection of index.php

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, joomla

The below illustrates the .htaccess code for a generating SEF url when joomla SEF is on in the backend.

```
## Begin - Joomla! core SEF Section.
#
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
#
# If the requested path and file is not /index.php and the request
# has not already been internally rewritten to the index.php script
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index\.php
# and the request is for something within the component folder,
# or for the site root, or for an extensionless URL, or the
# requested URL ends with one of the listed extensions
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /component/|(/[^.]*|\.(php|html?|feed|pdf|vcf|raw))$ [NC]
# and the requested path and file doesn't directly match a physical file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
# and the requested path and file doesn't directly match a physical folder
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# internally rewrite the request to the index.php script
RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
```

I have a simple problem which I'm not able to get my head around into. 
I put this condition so that if the url is domain.com/index.php then it should go to domain.com and this should happen only if the pattern matches exactly as index.php. 
However this happens for all urls.

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} [^.]*|/(index.php)$
RewriteRule ^index.php$ / [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> `it should go to domain.com and this should happen only if the pattern matches exactly as index.php. However this happens for all urls.`

It is due to the wrong regex you're using. Use this rule to remove `index.php` from URIs:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/administrator [NC]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*?)index\.php$ /$1 [L,R=302,NC,NE]
```

Comment: can you tell me why you haven't used $ at the end of RewriteCond since $ means the end of line doesn't it ?

Comment: Thanks for this. It mostly does what I want to do. However it also affects the administrator folder of joomla and doesn't allow me to login. Keeps redirecting to the login screen.. Can I somehow prevent this.

Comment: Thanks anubhava.. I just did that few minutes ago.. Was about to update my comment..

Comment: I want to ask you one more question why do we use index.php in ReWriteCond and again in RewriteRule I don't get it. I tried checking the docs but I'm still confused. !!

Comment: Actually there is way to capture that from `RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST}` as well but it is mostly due to easy of capturing I used `RewriteRule`.

Comment: sorry for reviving old post, but this is very close to what i want, however, how can i redirect this: http://domain.com/page/index.php to this: http://domain.com/page/ ?  what i get is this: http://domain.com/page/index.php redirecting to this: http://domain.com

Comment: With above rule it will redirect `domain.com/page/index.php` to `domain.com/page`